# How to prove this property of family of set: $\bigcap{(X\cup Y)}=\cap X \bigcap \cap Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If X and Y are two different family of sets. How can I prove $\bigcap{(X\cup Y)}=\cap X \bigcap \cap Y$?

I started with $z \in \bigcap{(X\cup Y)}$ then exist $A \in X \cup Y$ so that $z \in A$. Then we have two cases. When $A \in X$ and when $A \in Y$.
But what should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making some confusion. When $X$ is a set of sets, the notation
$$\bigcap X$$
is a shorter way of writing
$$\bigcap_{A \in X}A$$
This means that
$$\bigcap (X \cup Y) = \bigcap_{A \in X \cup Y} A$$
Now, let $z \in \bigcap_{A \in X \cup Y} A$. This is equivalent to saying that for all $A \in X \cup Y$, $z \in A$. In particular, for all $A \in X$, $z \in A$, so $z \in \bigcap X$. Similarly, $z \in \bigcap Y$. Hence $z \in \bigcap X \cap \bigcap Y$.

The converse is proved similarly.